# ошибка при доступе к «cdosys.dll» (Error accesing the OLE registry)

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-7

Возникла необходимость создать модуль «CDO_TLB». А как написано [тут](https://www.thoughtco.com/save-a-web-page-as-html-or-mht-1058361), его можно создать следующим способом: "Import Type Library", и нажать кнопку "Add" выделив при этом "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cdosys.dll". Вот при этом у меня вываливается ошибка:

> "Error accesing the OLE registry."

Вообще побегав по сети, пишут, что это старые версии Delphi, не могут прохавать новые библиотеки (Windows 10).

Тогда что мне делать?

P.S. Мне этот модуль нужен для сохранения "*.mht" файла на диске

Comment: Попробуйте из командной строки `tlibimp -P+ cdosys.dll`